# Azure Devops EF Core migration script GUID PK error

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, entity-framework-migrations, guid

I have 2 EF Core databases and one of them does have a table with a GUID as its primary key. I've never had any problems with running migrations but since I try to run migrations from my Azure Devops pipeline i do get an error.

I used the following code to create the script in my Azure pipeline:

```
- script: 'dotnet ef migrations script   --idempotent --output migrations.sql --project "".csproj --context ""'
displayName: Create EF migration Script
```

And when I try to run it, I get the following error in my Azure Devops pipeline:

> System.ArgumentException: Identity value generation cannot be used for the property 'id' on entity type '"" (Dictionary<string, object>)' because the property type is 'Guid'. Identity value generation can only be used with signed integer properties.

I tried to use the same script for the database that uses int as its primary key but there he has no problem with running the migration.

I also tried to remove `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` from my GUID PK and added

```
modelBuilder.Entity<users>().Property(p => p.id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

in my modelbuilder. But this resulted in the same error.

Comment: What version of EF Core are you using on local machine and Pipeline? When you set the GUID as Primary key, will the same script can work on your local machine?

Comment: EF Core Version 8.0.2. in both my local machine and pipeline. The same script works on my local machine but only gives problem in our Azure Pipeline.